# How can I separate signalsdata in buffer?

Tags: c++, qt, buffer, signal-processing, curve

I'm making signal processing using  qt ,I set up the desired the format   like this:

Comment: you set `SampleSize` to `8` but `Samples`is a 16bit array. Are you sure is correct??

Comment: I've edited, actually, I set sampleSize to 16 and my Samples is a 16bit array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `i` to index YVectorRight , but you step up `i` with 2 every iteration, so you'll skip every second index.

I.e. you have a typo.

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < countSamples ; ++j) {
      YVectorRight[j] =Samples[i++];
//                ^^
//              use j here, not i
      YVectorLeft[j] = Samples[i++];
 }
```